# I am trying to recreate this ui i made in figma to html, css and js

Tags: javascript, html, css, figma

I made a morphing text with covering text when scrolling but I cannot seem to fix it no matter what I try what is the best way to achieve this animation?
I am new to coding

```js
const blackBox = document.querySelector('#black-box');
window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

function handleScroll() {
  const scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  const fullHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  const height = `${(scrollTop / fullHeight) * 100}%`

  blackBox.style.height = height;
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 200vh;
  margin: 0;
}

#black-box {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="black-box"></div>
```

this is the link to the figma i made [Figma Link](https://www.figma.com/file/VaoGrrYi5YqgpiOvBzpeN4/Untitled?type=design&node-id=0%3A1&mode=design&t=kbrn6IQT7jyQiQRp-1)
[image: Basically What it looks like]

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Be sure to capitalize proper nouns and initialisms appropriately.

Comment: Isn't this just a HTML page, double the height of the viewport, with the top half colored white and the bottom half colored black? The somewhat tricky bit is the text, it should be [fixed in the viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) and [invert the background color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode).